# Specifies that I have problems with my conn.open and my Conn.Close

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is how I select some content twice and when I get into the middle to select so like that it gives me trouble to select something on file.

The problem I have never seen before,

I think it's something with `conn.open()` and `Conn.Close()`

my code looks like this:

```
int prisId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Id"]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ppId", prisId);

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT priser FROM Priser WHERE Id = @ppId;";

conn.Open();
SqlDataReader readerPriser = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (readerPriser.Read())
{
    PanelerrorHandelsbetingelser.Visible = false;

    string Brugerid = Session["id"].ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brugerid", Brugerid);

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id, brugernavn, fornavn, efternavn FROM brugere WHERE Id = @brugerid;";

    SqlDataReader readerBrugerid = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (readerPriser.Read())
    {
        Session["id"] = readerBrugerid["id"].ToString();
        Session["brugernavn"] = readerBrugerid["brugernavn"].ToString();
        Session["fornavn"] = readerBrugerid["fornavn"].ToString();
        Session["efternavn"] = readerBrugerid["efternavn"].ToString();

        Session["adresse"] = TextBoxAdresse.Text;
        Session["post"] = TextBoxPost.Text;
        Session["telefon"] = TextBoxTelefon.Text;

        Session["prisen"] = readerPriser["priser"].ToString();

        LabelErrorBuyNow.Text = " - Yeaaa Jesper!";
    }
    else
    {
        LabelErrorBuyNow.Text = " - Der findes intet med dit brugerid!";
    }
}
conn.Close();
```

problems come after line 9-10

The problem is such that it appears this one mistake on my part: **There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.**

Comment: What is the problem?  What is the question?

Comment: You need to post the exception or message that you are getting for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry @dodexahedron and i have do it now! :),

Comment: `SqlDataReader readerBrugerid = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (readerPriser.Read())` should be `SqlDataReader readerBrugerid = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (readerBrugerid.Read())`

Comment: @prospector It will not agree to,

Comment: possible duplicate of [DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605504/datareader-associated-with-this-command-which-must-be-closed-first)

Comment: @walther It helps not at all still :(

Answer (score 0):

Always remember to release resources after they are used. So at the method end, you should:

```
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
readerPriser.Close();
conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception tells you exactly what is wrong.
You have tried to run two SqlDataReaders over the same connection without either specifying MultipleActiveResultSets=True in your connection string or else first closing the first reader.

You have three options:

1. Use a second connection to run the second SqlDataReader.
2. Add     "MultipleActiveResultSets=True" to your connection string.
3. Close the first SqlDataReader before using the second.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the readerPriser first be
readerPriser.Close();
Then affiliate the same command with next reader.
Always close the readers after using them.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here. First of all, you are not placing all of your `IDisposable` objects into `using` blocks. Second, you are reusing the same `SqlCommand` for different queries. Third, your second `Read` call is using the wrong `SqlDataReader`.

Try

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(...)){
    conn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand selectPriser = new SqlCommand("SELECT priser FROM Priser WHERE Id = @ppId;", conn))
    {
        selectPriser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ppId", prisId);

        using (SqlDataReader readerPriser = selectPriser.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (readerPriser.Read())
            {
                // ...
                using (SqlCommand selectBrugere = new SqlCommand("SELECT id, brugernavn, fornavn, efternavn FROM brugere WHERE Id = @brugerid;"){
                    string Brugerid = Session["id"].ToString();
                    selectBrugere.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brugerid", Brugerid);
                    using (SqlDataReader readerBrugerid = selectBrugere.ExecuteReader()){
                        if (readerBrugerid.Read()){
                            // ...
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It helps not at all still :(